# How to set a dynamic value as the name of rendered pdf page

Tags: visualforce

We have created a VF Page to render as pdf. This page is created as a custom button on the case detail page.

Is there a way to save the pdf with the case number as the name of the pdf..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the content-disposition in the VF controller? e.g.

```
    String myGeneratedFileName = case.CaseNumber +'.pdf';
    Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename='+myGeneratedFilename);
```